# Symbol in MatLab / Simulink

Tags: matlab, symbols, simulink

input temperature:

[image: input temperature]

input parameters with calculation:

[image: input parameters with calculation]

Where can I find these symbols in Simulink

Answer (score 0):

They are [From](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/from.html) and [Goto](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/goto.html) blocks. I would advise using them as little as possible, as they make a Simulink model more difficult to read in my view. You also need to consider the [Goto Tag Visibility](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/gototagvisibility.html) when using Goto blocks.